# Dojo/on and the capture phase

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Is there a way to trigger an event in the capture phase (instead of the bubbling phase) with dojo/on?

Comment: The short answer is no; however, why are you trying to trigger in the capture phase? maybe there's another way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here looking for info on the predecessor of on() - dojo.connect(). For what it's worth, dojo.connect() does not appear to support event listeners for the capture phase. It works by adding the event handler to the DOM node as a field, e.g., `node["mouseclick"] = ...` Since you have to use addEventListener to receive events during the capture phase, my deduction is that dojo.connect() can't do it.

What you can do is add some event listeners to a custom object on the dom node and then use dojo.connect() on those handlers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function forwardCaptureEvent(e) {
            var listener = this.captureEventHandlers[e.type];
            if (listener != null) listener.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        function enableCaptureEvent(domNode, eventType) {
            if (domNode.captureEventHandlers == null) domNode.captureEventHandlers = {};
            var evtHandlers = domNode.captureEventHandlers;
            if (evtHandlers[eventType] == null) evtHandlers[eventType] = function(e) {};
            domNode.addEventListener(eventType, forwardCaptureEvent, true);
        }

        function logEvent(label, e) {
            dojo.byId("log").innerHTML += label + " " + e.currentTarget.id + " " + e.type + " " + [ '', 'capturing', 'target', 'bubbling' ][ e.eventPhase ] + "<br/>";
        }

        function logCaptureEvent(e) { 
            logEvent("capture phase:", e);
        }

        function logBubbleEvent(e) { 
            logEvent("bubble phase:", e);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            enableCaptureEvent(dojo.byId("test"), "click");
            dojo.connect(dojo.byId("test").captureEventHandlers, "click", logCaptureEvent);
            dojo.connect(dojo.byId("test"), "click", logBubbleEvent);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" style="background: darkorange; padding: 20px;">
        <div style="background: gold; padding: 20px;">
            <div style="background: cornsilk; ">Click me.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So here `enableCaptureEvent` and `forwardCaptureEvent` are my helper functions. `enableCaptureEvent` creates the custom object of capture event listeners on the DOM node that I was talking about and then `forwardCaptureEvent` is used to actually receive the capture events and forward them to these listeners.

Then to use these helpers, you call `enableCaptureEvent` with a DOM node and the name of the event you want to connect to. Then to connect to it, you connect to the custom object on the DOM node which I called "captureEventHandlers". This is what I'm doing in the `onload` handler. I'm also doing a normal `dojo.connect` to show this doesn't interfere with catching normal bubble events.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible, you can use aspects.
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect

Especially before or around ;)

Before

> The module also includes a before function that provides before advice
>   to a method. The provided advising function will be called before the
>   main method is called. The before function's signature is:

```
before(target, methodName, advisingFunction);
```

Comment: I don't believe that this will help. AOP is for adding advising methods to object methods. Precisely which method would you recommend advising here?

Comment: Well assuming he would be connecting to a "click" event on some widget, he could use before(targetWidget, "onClick", function(){ // hatever he wants to do here, for example check for sources, target or whatever });
I wonder why you would not only downvote but also give false information without first making sure of what the guy wants... Maybe I should also downvote you for the sake of it?

Comment: The advising method would be called before `onClick` is called, but `onClick` wouldn't be called until the bubbling phase. Since the OP explicitly asked for a way to trigger event handlers during the capturing phase, this answer doesn't address the posed question at all.

Comment: We're not even sure what the guy really wants... It might be just "a way to intercept an event before the action on this event is called". Funny how you changed your answer from "No it is not possible" to "Normally not but depends on...". In this case providing information that might help is better than saying simply "no".