# Fire mouseup event only for outer div

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have an HTML element (form element - textbox) inside another series of divs. 
I created listener for mouseup event on the outer div, but it fires when I click on the textbox.

I thought it would only fire when mouseup on the outer div since I attached the listener to that element - not to the textbox

Is there a way to prevent it from firing when 'mouseup' fires on the textbox?

```js
require([
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom"
], function (
TextBox,
on,
dom) {
    var box = new TextBox({
        name: "any",
        value: "",
        placeholder: "Type anything here"
    }, "textBox");
    
    var canvas = dom.byId("outerDiv");
    on(canvas, "mouseup", function (e) {
    alert();
    });
});
dojo.require("dijit.form.anyText");
 var textBox = dijit.byId("textBox");
   console.log( "--- >> "+textBox.get("value"));
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<Div id="outerDiv" style="width: 3in; height: 3in; border: 1px solid;border-color:black; cursor: pointer;">
  <Div id="innerDiv" style="height: auto; border: 1px solid;border-color:blue;">
    <div  id="textBox" readonly></div>
  </Div>
</Div>
```

Comment: Instead on trying to prevent the event, I would check in the event is fired on the element where the listener is assigned: `if(event.target === event.currentTarget){...}`

Comment: @FlorentB. Sounds good. You might consider posting an answer making that argument.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the text box, the event ["bubbles up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) to the outer elements.

JavaScript's [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) "prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases".

Below is an example in pure JavaScript, but see also [dojo.stopEvent](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/stopEvent.html).

```js
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('outerDiv');
var textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');

outerDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  console.log('mouse up on outer div');
});
textBox.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('mouse up on text box');
});
```

```css
#outerDiv {
  width: 3in;
  height: 3in;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#innerDiv {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<Div id="outerDiv">
  <Div id="innerDiv">
    <div id="textBox" readonly>textbox</div>
  </Div>
</Div>
```

---

### Edit

Here's a Dojo example:

```js
require([
  "dijit/form/TextBox",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/dom"
], function(
  TextBox,
  on,
  dom) {

  var box = new TextBox({
    name: "any",
    value: "",
    placeholder: "Type anything here"
  }, "textBox");

  var canvas = dom.byId("outerDiv");

  on(box, "mouseup", function(e) {
    console.log('mouse up on text box');
    dojo.stopEvent(e);
  });

  on(canvas, "mouseup", function(e) {
    console.log('mouse up on outer div');
  });

});
```

```css
#outerDiv {
  width: 3in;
  height: 3in;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#innerDiv {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<Div id="outerDiv">
  <Div id="innerDiv">
    <div id="textBox" readonly>textbox</div>
  </Div>
</Div>
```

Comment: child event always fires before the parent?

Comment: That depends. Here's an informative article about [event order](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). Also see [event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) and [Bubbling and Capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Comment: I'm definitely not a Dojo expert, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340194/dojo-on-and-the-capture-phase), Dojo "not appear to support event listeners for the capture phase". So in this context, I'd say yes: the event fires first on the child and then bubbles up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the id before creating the alert

```
on(canvas, "mouseup", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == "outerDiv") {
       alert();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgi/nyvLvg6f/1/)